# Saving changes to xlsxwriter workbook without closing or stopping the program

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I have a workbook and another huge dataset of samples. I read the samples in smaller parts each containing 1000 points of data (or let's just say n samples). Then I do some stuff on them and write the results in the workbook (I have just one workbook that I want all the results to be saved there.)

Let's say the dataset format is like the following:

```
record 1: columns [a, b, c]
```

after doing the stuff I have another column added and I need to write the following into the workbook:

```
record 1: columns [a, b, c, d]
```

The problem is that right now, I cannot see the actual excel file except I close the workbook or stop the program, while I need to see the results (updated records) real time in the actual file after each round that I am done with processing a part.

My question is then how can we save the changes real time and be able to see the updated excel file without closing the workbook and while the program is still running?

Answer (score 2):

That isn’t possible with XlsxWriter. You can only close and save the file once.

Comment: Thanks! Spent some time to figure it out. At least now I know I should not more!